# python flask IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied

Tags: flask, setup-deployment

I am trying to deploy my flask project .I got an error when access to the website,Internal Server Error.I check the error_log,which says

```
**"IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/apps/microblog/tmp/microblog.log'
[Fri Jan 08 13:06:41 2016] [warn] [client 115.59.229.183] (104)Connection reset by peer: mod_fcgid: error reading data from FastCGI server"**
```

I have chmod 777 on the tmp file,but it didn't help.
by the way ,I have config conf/httpd.conf

```
FcgidIPCDir /tmp
AddHandler fcgid-script .fcgi
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /home/apps/microblog/app/static
    Alias /static /home/apps/microblog/app/static
ScriptAlias / /home/apps/microblog/runp-mysql.fcgi/
```

Comment: What's the permissions on the directory itself?

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  10 apps apache 4096  Jan  8 10:56 microblog